# How to set cursor's position in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to auto-capitalise names' first characters in an input field. The capitalisation works, but when I replace the element with the new string the cursor automatically jumps to the end of the string, which is very annoying.

Here's my code:

```
$('#firstnameid, #surnameid').on('keyup', function() {
    capitalise_first($(this));
});

function capitalise_first(elem) {
    var value = elem.val();
    var capital = value[0].toUpperCase();
    var capital_string = capital + value.substr(1, value.length -1);
    elem.val(capital_string);
}
```

The first and surname fields are just simple text inputs.

I've seen a lot of other posts regarding this issue or similar ones, but none of them are seeming to do anything for me. Usually there is a pretty simple solution to these sorts of issues, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set cursor position in textBox javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579014/set-cursor-position-in-textbox-javascript)

Comment: what is your problem?